# Can we natively boot Hyper V VHD in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I have created a VHD using Hyper V Manager in Windows 2008 R2 . I have 2 questions:

Can I natively boot in Win 2008 R2 ?
Can I natively boot in Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/windows-7-boot-from-vhd.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite brief, and I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

You can boot a VHD file within a Hyper-V VM as long as that VHD is set up to boot through a conventional BIOS (not EFI) and it has drivers for a parallel IDE controller enabled within it.  The rest will (more or less) take care of itself as Plug and Play runs within the VM.

You can boot a VHD file outside of a VM if the OS on that VHD is Windows 7 and there are drivers within the OS for your hardware and they are enabled.

You can enable the full set of drivers using sysprep, so that the VHD can boot either way.

Hyper-V manager is for using VMs.  It has nothing to do with booting a VHD outside of a VM.

Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can boot from VHD in Windows 7 **Enterprise** or **Ultimate** editions only.
You can also boot from VHD in 2008 R2 as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean can you move the VHD between the VPC software in Windows 7 and Hyper-V?

If so, then yes. a VHD can move between 7 and 2008.

However, a virtual machine shouldnt.
A VM going from 7 to 2008 works, going from 2008 to 7 requires a hack and provides some weird instability issues, fine for testing/disaster recovery but thats about it.